# Why doesn't Google Charts work with this date format?

Tags: php, sql, json

I am using PHP and SQL to generate charts using Google Charts.

I have a particular chart that I've started but Google Charts doesn't seem to like the date format that is returned by SQL.

**Code**

```
<?php 

include('core/connection.php');

$stid = oci_parse($conn, "     
  SELECT EntryDate AS \"Date\", COUNT(OrderNo) AS \"Orders\"
  FROM Orders
  WHERE EntryDate > '01-MAY-2014'
  AND CustomerNo = 1
  GROUP BY EntryDate
");
oci_execute($stid);

$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

    array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'date'),
    array('label' => 'Orders', 'type' => 'number')

);

$rows = array();
while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)) {
    $temp = array();

    $date = new \DateTime($row['Date']);            
    $dateStringForGoogleCharts = $date->format("Y/m/d H:i");

    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $dateStringForGoogleCharts);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Orders']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

oci_close($conn);

?>

<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
      var options = {
          width:  1600,
          height: 800
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please can someone provide an example using this code on what I must do to get Google Charts to accept this date format?

### Update

I have updated the code to generate the date in the format that Google Charts expects (thanks for the answer), but now when visiting the page I see an error message in a red box saying `undefined is not a function`.

Comment: which database oracle , mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this successfully with the following JS:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addRows(<?=$json?>);

    var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {displayAnnotations: true, colors: ['blue', 'red']});
}
```

And, server-side, after getting the data from the database in PHP I use DateTime to format the string for the JSON, like this:

```
$date = new \DateTime($row['date']);            
$dateStringForGoogleCharts = $date->format("Y/m/d H:i");
```

With the key bit being the format of "Y/m/d H:i" - that's how Google Charts like it.

My advice is to convert the date format coming from your database to this format using [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).  I seem to remember some trial and error getting to a format accepted by the API, but that format definately works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm by no means an expert, I'm new to all this but I'm getting there slowly. I've tried following your code. I have `$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['DATE']);` I'm guessing this is the date row returned by SQL so an example of the current format being returned is `08-MAY-2014`. What does Google Charts expect and could I just wrap this `$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['DATE']);` line in something to convert it there and then?

Comment: My advice is to convert the date format coming from your database to the format "Y/m/d H:i" using DateTime. I seem to remember some trial and error getting to a format accepted by the API, but that format definately works.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to check the question that I updated? I'm getting an error message now `undefined is not a function` in a red box.

Comment: That HTML and JS works for me, with an arbitrary JSON string taken from the Google Charts site.  Can you post the string held in $jsonTable here?

Comment: `{"cols":[{"label":"Date","type":"date"},{"label":"Orders","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":2014},{"v":8}]},{"c":[{"v":2014},{"v":10}]},{"c":[{"v":2014},{"v":9}]},{"c":[{"v":2014},{"v":9}]}]}`.

Comment: Well, you're problem is in there, somewhere.  Try http://jsonlint.com/, paste it in, validate it it, see if you can find out where it is going wrong.

Comment: I see that it is converting my date from SQL but it is only outputting a year and not the format that Google Charts requires ...